# HTTP to HTTPS NEW SSL

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I have in my .htaccess.bak file
but there is a problem in getting it indexed on google webmaster tool, the webmaster tool says

> Failure reason: Could not find your site. Please check that you provided the correct URL for your property.

There is the same problem in google my business page when I click on the website button the error message occur

> Object Moved
>   This document may be found here

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

link to website https://www.sgsconsulting.com/ (if URL doesn't work add a backslash after the URL)

link to google my business page https://www.google.com/search?q=sgs+technical+services+private+limited+indore+madhya+pradesh&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN786IN786&oq=sgs+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i59j0j69i57j0.1903j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

The problem has occurred since I added SSL to the website some days ago.

Suggest me code change in .htaccess.bak file or any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: .bak? That's a typical backup file extension and not used by Apache. Is that the real name?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on` <- you shouldn't need to check for an environment variable there,it should just be `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` - presumably the `<VirtualHost>` is properly configured for port 443 with the SSL configuration in?

Comment: yes the file name is .htaccess.bak , Is .htaccess.bak different from .htaccess

Comment: Yes! Apache looks for .htaccess only.